# Decryption does not work on Production(Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7) and works on UAT(SUSE based linux distro)

Tags: java, linux, encryption, redhat, des

I'm using  DES  for encryption/decryption as its not recommended but its an old code so i could'nt move to AES, now my code working fine on local environment(i.e mac ) with production db, also its working fine on UAT which is SUSE based linux distro but decryption not working on Production which is redhat based enironment. on Production it throws "Input length (with padding) not multiple of 8 bytes" Illegal Block size exception

```
@Service
public class EncryptionUtil {

    private static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(EncryptionUtil.class);
    @Autowired
    GpsCacheManager gpsCacheManager;
    private Cipher ecipher;
    private Cipher dcipher;
    @Autowired
    private StringUtils stringUtils;

    public EncryptionUtil() throws Exception {
        ecipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES");
        dcipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES");
        initCipher();
    }


    private void initCipher() {
        try {
            String response = “[-3232, -34, -98, 111, -222, 33, -22, 55]”;
            String[] byteValues = response.substring(1, response.length() - 1).split(",");
            byte[] bytes = new byte[byteValues.length];
            for (int i = 0, len = bytes.length; i < len; i++) {
                bytes[i] = Byte.parseByte(byteValues[i].trim());
            }

            SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(bytes, "DES");
            ecipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
            dcipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }


    public String encryptUTF8(String str) throws Exception {
        // Encode the string into bytes using utf-8
        byte[] utf8 = str.getBytes("UTF8");

        // Encrypt
        byte[] enc = ecipher.doFinal(utf8);
        // Encode bytes to base64 to get a string
        return new String(Base64.encodeBase64(enc));
    }

    public String decryptUTF8(String str) throws Exception {

        if (stringUtils == null) {
            stringUtils = new StringUtils();
        }
        //do not decrypt if a valid email.
        if (stringUtils.isValidEmail(str)) {
            return str;
        }
        // Decode base64 to get bytes
        byte[] dec = Base64.decodeBase64(str.getBytes());

        byte[] utf8 = null;
        try {
            utf8 = dcipher.doFinal(dec);
        } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
            return str;
        }
        // Decode using utf-8
        return new String(utf8, "UTF8");
    }
}
```

Comment: How can UAT be an exact replica when the distribution is entirely different? That's *not* What people mean with "exact replica"

Comment: When you say it's not working in prod, what do you mean?

Comment: the same key and same db is used on both evironment but result different

Comment: Then your input data are different (with wrong key you would likely hit a padding exception). There is no reason why would  this Java code differently on different environments (except that the Cipher object is not thread-safe). You will need to find and provide more information.

Comment: @gusto2 if i run my application locally on mac with production db then also decryption working fine , but only reason is i run it on production envirenment then its not working

Comment: There are some crypto anti-patterns here by relying on defaults. The answer by @Joop Eggen below highlights one. Another is here: `Cipher.getInstance("DES");`. Always specify the full *algorithm/mode/padding* string to `Cipher.getInstance()`.

Comment: Another problem is your exception handling in `decryptUTF8`. You catch the `IllegalBlockSizeException` and silently return the base64 encoded ciphertext. You should at least log the exception so you can become aware of it and fix the bug. You also don't mention how the result is "different".

Comment: @JamesKPolk one uat this method decrypt data properly while on production its gives data in encrypted form

Comment: Well, that could be because you are receiving an `IllegalBlockSizeException`. Read *all* of my comments and Joop Eggen's answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue with `String.getBytes()` and `new String(byte[])` which are platform dependent and should not be used here. At the same time I replaced that Base64 class with the standard java's [Base64](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html), that was intended to replace several Base64 implementations some ten years ago.

```
public String encryptUTF8(String str) throws Exception {
    // Encode the string into bytes using utf-8
    byte[] utf8 = str.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

    // Encrypt
    byte[] enc = ecipher.doFinal(utf8);
    // Encode bytes to base64 to get a string
    return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(enc));
    //Old class: return new String(Base64.encodeBase64(enc), StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
}

public String decryptUTF8(String str) throws Exception {

     if (stringUtils == null) {
            stringUtils = new StringUtils();
     }
     //do not decrypt if a valid email.
     if (stringUtils.isValidEmail(str)) {
        return str;
     }
     // Decode base64 to get bytes
     //byte[] dec = Base64.getDecoder().decode(str.getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII));    
     byte[] dec = Base64.getDecoder().decode(str);    
     try {
         byte[] utf8 = dcipher.doFinal(dec);
         // Decode using utf-8
         return new String(utf8, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
     } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
         return str;
     }
}
```

There is one problem: `String` is for Unicode text, with two-byte `char`s (UTF-16).
This means any `byte[]` value must be text in some encoding, and with that encoding converted to a String. Any arbitrary `byte[]` value will not be a valid String. Especially on Linux with the preeminent UTF-8 encoding that will corrupt data.

The problem probably resides in `decryptUTF8`. If in the original code the default encoding is a single byte encoding, everything is swallowed as-is. For Linux, UTF-8, erroneous UTF-8 multi-byte sequences might be encountered. *Or the encoding is a 7-bits ASCII.*

In general keep `String` and `byte[]` apart; use `byte[]` for non-text binary data.

Comment: I don't find this very convincing. Are there any platforms where the default charset is incompatible with US_ASCII? It's possible but not likely, thus not likely to be causing the errors.

Comment: For Base64 text, whose bytes always are US_ASCII (unless EBCDIC) that is right. But for arbitrary bytes it is a problem. I am not entirely convinced too, I would more have tipped on `return str;` causing havoc; any such special flow of control. The Cipher usage seems correct: doFinal reinitializes for the next call. Red Hat has special concurrency optimisation, but that should not play a role here.

Comment: I don't see anywhere in his code where he is putting arbitrary bytes in the `new String()` constructor.

Comment: @JamesKPolk you are right. Though `Base64.decodeBase64(str.getBytes());` would be a bit weird if the encoding would be UTF-16 On the Red Hat machine. Far fetched. Don't you find that `new String/getBytes` creepy? It introduces a platform dependency. Maybe the error is in the API usage though. BTW **that -3232 should be a typo.** Otherwise I do not see something.

Comment: It would all fail miserably if the default charset were UTF-16, so it is *a* mistake to not explicitly specify the charset, but probably not *the* mistake in this case. Though it could be. OP doesn't really specify in any detail what the problem is. That's why I added a few comments to OPs question.

Comment: @JamesKPolk thanks, I should have started with some questions too. Constructive remarks on your side.

Comment: j8+ `Base64.getDecoder().decode(String)` is simpler and avoids any issue from default encoding. `-222` is also out of range for `byte` and both of them should throw `NumberFormatException` which OP doesn't indicate. Plus the 'smartquotes' used in the posted source don't compile.

Comment: @JoopEggen i have tried your code as well but it still not working , throws "Input length (with padding) not multiple of 8 bytes" exception

Comment: Padding is default with the standard `Base64` (the Encoder has a `.withoutPadding()` so check the string, probably it is not something Base64 encoded.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 thanks; used your suggestion, I was too concentrated on any charset problem.